# UITabBarControllerのアイコンのカスタマイズやサイズ変更について

Tags: xcode, storyboard

UITabBarControllerにてタブにカスタムアイコンを表示させたいのですが、
このタブのアイコンをカスタマイズさせる方法といえば、Apple規定のUITabBarControllerを元として設定した、画像を線画のように切り抜いた形で表示させるものだと思います。

また背景の画像をカスタムする、という方法も、Apple規定のUITabBarControllerを基盤として背景の画像を変えるものだけでした。
サイズも同様に、Storyboard内では変更できないみたいです。

UITabBarController自体(ないしはアイコン自体)のサイズをカスタマイズし、かつ自分で作成したカラーのついたImageのものに変更し、実装したいのですが、これはXcode内で実装できるようなものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> UITabBarControllerにてタブにカスタムアイコンを表示させたい

というアプローチは正しくありません。アプローチの相手は、View Controllerのほうです。
Storyboard上で、View Controllerのタブバーにあるアイコンをクリックすると、下図のAttributed Inspectorになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

System Itemを「Custom」にし、Imageを任意の画像に指定します。画像は「線画」である必要はなく、一辺32ピクセル以下のビットマップ画像でも可です。

プログラムでTabbar ControllerにView Controllerを追加するとき、アイコンを指定するには、このようにします。（このサンプルコードは、任意のView Controllerクラスに記述するものとします。）

```
let thirdViewController = UIViewController()
thirdViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor() // View Controllerのカスタマイズ
thirdViewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "third.png") // ファイル名は任意に。
var viewcontrollers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
viewcontrollers?.append(thirdViewController)
self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers!, animated: true)
```

このように、タブバーアイコンの設定の対象は、UITabBarControllerではなく、UIViewControllerであることが、おわかりになると思います。

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます。ViewControllerにて設置の方法は理解致しました。たった今、実装してみたのですが、もしかして32ピクセル以上の画像だと切れて表示されてしまったり、カラーがついていると色が反映されなかったり、ということはあるでしょうか？またその場合に、タブ自体の縦のサイズ変更は不可能でしょうか？

Comment: やってみればわかることについては、いちいちお答えいたしません。また、アイコンは、原寸大で作成するのが、プログラミング以前の原則と思います。    
タブの高さの変更は、可能不可能の前に、やっていいこととは思えません。

Comment: タブの高さの変更はやってはいけないこと、なのですね！理解致しました。有り難うございます。

Comment: @らりん 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers